# Why isn't JUnit4 imports recognized even though JUnit4 is in my effective pom.xml?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, junit, pom.xml

I am getting build errors in my Eclipse project like the following:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

The import org.junit.Assert cannot be resolved
```

But if you see the effective pom.xml, the JUnit4 dependency is there:

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.13</version>
  </dependency>
```

The error disappears if I add this dependency explicitly to my `pom.xml`.

**Why is that the case ? If its already there shouldn't it be used ?**

This is my `pom.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.product</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>Test</name>
    <description>Project</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>8</java.version>
        <azure.version>2.3.3</azure.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic -->

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/de.flapdoodle.embed/de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.flapdoodle.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo</artifactId>

            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.redisson</groupId>
            <artifactId>redisson</artifactId>
            <version>3.14.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>

        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-starter-azure-storage</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>

        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-devtools -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>

            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.javax.persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.modelmapper/modelmapper -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.persistence/persistence-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.integration/spring-integration-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!--<dependency> <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId> 
            </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.querydsl/querydsl-mongodb -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.querydsl/querydsl-apt -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
            <!--<version>4.3.1</version> -->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>applicationinsights-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>applicationinsights-logging-logback</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-api -->
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <!-- ID generator repo setup -->
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>gitlab-maven</id>
            <url>https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/22715350/packages/maven</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>gitlab-maven</id>
            <url>https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/22715350/packages/maven</url>
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>gitlab-maven</id>
            <url>https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/22715350/packages/maven</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>


    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
                <artifactId>azure-spring-boot-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${azure.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>process</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/java</outputDirectory>
                            <processor>
                                org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongoAnnotationProcessor
                            </processor>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Be careful the dependency is in the dependencyManagement and not in the dependencies. That means you have to simply write the dependency but without version (that will be controlled by the spring-boot parent)... of course you have to add the scope:test...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dependency you have mentioned is in the [`dependencyManagement`](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-dependencies/2.3.3.RELEASE/pom) and not in the dependencies. That means you have to simply write the dependency but without version (that will be controlled by the spring-boot parent) of course you have to add the scope:test like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot is using JUnit 5 and if you want to run your JUnit4 tests with `mvn test` you have to remove the exclusion:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

The vintage engine runs the JUnit4 tests.

And as khmarbaise you have to add Junit 4 that your test compiles:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Not with 2.3.X? as far as I know starting with 2.4.0 only... ?

Comment: I am confused as to what `org.junit.vintage` has to do with `junit4` ?

Comment: Nothing. You can run JUnit 3/4 test with JUnit Jupiter (engine) (aka JUnit 5) if you like...

Comment: @khmarbaise I'm sorry I mixed running and compiling. Please checkout my updated answer.